# Proving piecewise function is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, piecewise-continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            2x & \quad x \text{ is rational} \\
            -2x & \quad x \text{ is irrational }
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Show that $f$ is discontinuous at every point $x_0 \neq 0$.

My idea to show this is to consider when $x_0$ is rational and then consider when it is irrational. Then using the density of the rationals we have sequences which converge to $x_0$. Then use The Divergence Criterion for Functional Limits Theorem to finish the proof. Is this along the right track?

Comment: For reference, you'll probably find the proof that the Dirichlet function is discontinuous everywhere somewhat fruitful with this. I haven't tried the proof for myself, but I imagine showing the discontinuity will have a similar flavor, and then you have the special case of $0$ to handle. On the other hand, here's a similar exercise, a bit closer to the flavor of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369895/show-that-a-modified-dirichlet-function-is-continuous-at-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$. Take a sequence $(r_n)$ of rational numbers and a sequence $(s_n)$ of irrational numbers with $r_n \to x_0$ and $s_n \to x_0$.

Then: $f(r_n) =2r_n \to 2x_0$ and $f(s_n) =-2s_n \to -2x_0$.

This shows that $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$, if $x_0 \ne 0.$

Comment: You get the final line by the Divergence Criterion for Functional Limits?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then we have $ \lim f(r_n)= \lim f(s_n)$, hence $2x_0=-2x_0$, thus $x_0=0$.